# Need to return postOrder tree from inOrder and preOrder

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I have been given a task  that says that i have to return the postOrder of a  binary tree from its preOder and inOrder . Doing it with papper and pencil is easy , but the task is to develop a java function that does it automaticlly . It must be done in java .

I have found one solution to the excersice but it was made in c++ which makes it imposible for me to translate , i have tryed an online translator but it returns unusable java code

```
 void post(char *pre,char *in,char *pos,int n)
{
  int longIzqda;

  if(n!=0){
    pos[n-1]=pre[0];
    longIzqda=strchr(in,pre[0])-in;
    post (pre+1,in,pos,longIzqda);
    post (pre+1+longIzqda,in+1+longIzqda,pos+longIzqda,n-1-longIzqda);
  }
}
```

```
package include;

import com.mtsystems.coot.NativeHelper;
import com.mtsystems.coot.String8;

public class String {
   static {
       // The online demo uses the example library "libc.so.6".
       // Have a look at the translated programs for real values.
       NativeHelper h = NativeHelper.get("libc.so.6");
       h.bindDirect(String.class);
   }

   public static native String8 strchr(String8 s, int c);
}


// ----- ----- Class 2: DemoTranslation ----- -----

package demo;

import static com.mtsystems.coot.NativeInformation.dataDistance;
import static com.mtsystems.coot.String8.nnc;
import static include.String.strchr;

import com.mtsystems.coot.String8;

public class DemoTranslation {
   public static void post(String8 pre, String8 in, String8 pos, int n) {
       int longIzqda;

       if(n != 0) {
           pos.set(n - 1, pre.get(0));
           longIzqda = (int)dataDistance(in, strchr(in, pre.get(0)));
           post(nnc(pre).shift(1), in, pos, longIzqda);
           post(nnc(pre).shift(1 + longIzqda), nnc(in).shift(1 + longIzqda), nnc(pos).shift(longIzqda), n - 1 - longIzqda);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Pre, In, and Post order traversal are all essentially the same, just swapping the order of the function calls. Pre: print(), go(left), go(right)  In go(left), print(), go(right) post go(left), go(right), print().

Comment: @SephB His task (while not stated clearly) is to build string with postorder for some tree described by two strings containing pre- and in-order `"abc","bac" => "bca"`

Comment: @MBo Ahh, I didn't get that. That is a much more interesting assignment. In that case, only one of the other traversals should be needed to construct the missing one. As long as the data consists of single chars or otherwise delineated nicely.

Comment: @SephB Sometimes different trees might produce the same traversal (note tree is not necessary complete). But two kinds of traversals give full information about binary tree structure. Yes, assignment is very interesting and provides good expierence.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the C++ code could be ported. Three extra parameters are used to represent the indexes in the strings/character-arrays passed as first three arguments.

```
public static void post(String pre, String in, char[] pos, int preIdx, int inIdx, int posIdx, int n) {
    if (n == 0) return;
    pos[posIdx+n-1] = pre.charAt(preIdx);
    int longIzqda = in.indexOf(pre.charAt(preIdx), inIdx) - inIdx;
    post(pre, in, pos, preIdx+1, inIdx, posIdx, longIzqda);
    post(pre, in, pos, preIdx+1+longIzqda, inIdx+1+longIzqda, posIdx+longIzqda, n-1-longIzqda);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Example use
    String pre = "5213476";
    String in = "1234567";
    int n = pre.length();
    char[] post = new char[n];
    post(pre, in, post, 0, 0, 0, n);
    System.out.println(new String(post));
}
```